# react-native-video black screen on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

**Current behavior**

I have a list a social networking app that has videos and images (under 10 Mb each).
There is a screen with the user's feed, organized in a FlatList, in which i am loading for now only (!) two videos and one image. The app shows black screen in the place of the Video component, only on Android. The black screen problem does not happen in iOS! (I presume because the way memory management and how scroll lists are done in iOS)

**Reproduction steps**

This is my code for Video:

```
          <Video
            source={{ uri: this.state.uri }}
             ref={(ref) => {
               this.player = ref
             }}
             paused={this.state.paused}
             resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode}

             onLoad={this.handleLoad}
             onEnd={this.handleEnd.bind(this)}
             style={[this.state.style, { backgroundColor: '#3d3d3d' }]}
          />
```

also, if I add in AndroidManifest:

The memory consumed by the app as seen in Android Studio is somewhere at 170Mb, and growing.

**Expected behavior**

I expected to show the video.

**Platform**

Environment:

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Node: 8.10.0

Yarn: 1.5.1

npm: 5.6.0

Watchman: 4.9.0

Xcode: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000

Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4670197

Packages: (wanted => installed)

react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0

react-native: 0.54.4 => 0.54.4

Which player are you experiencing the problem on:
I am using the Video tag from : import Video from 'react-native-video';

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7q9kejiabs7y88/CrashVideo.mp4?dl=0

**Questions**

1) what is the solution to this?

2) Is this related to memory issues? When I load 10 more videos, the app crashes because of an error (as I see in Crashlytics) called 'Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError'.
Does the library react-native-video not load when there is high memory used?

3) does the FlatList on Android unload from memory the images/videos when I scroll them outside of view? Otherwise, If I go down with scrolling , do I continually add images / videos to the app memory and it will eventually crash?

4) Is another solution for performance for video? I am thinking react-native-thumbnail to show initially the thumbnail to not download the whole video. I am having trouble installing the library (issue #35 on https://github.com/phuochau/react-native-thumbnail/issues/35 ) , do you know of a better way to get the video thumbnail? (so that instead of showing videos in feed, i show them on thumbnail touch in a different screen).

5) does the Exoplayer eliminate this problem?

This is I believe the greatest challenge with this app so far. Please contribute what solutions you have found to apps with feeds with videos.
(I have posted the question on Github here, but sometimes I only get responses on SO: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1318 )

Thank you!